# Suppose that $\Delta u = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\int_{\{|x - y| < 1\}} |u(y)| dy < C, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $u$ is constant.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose that $\Delta u = 0$ in the weak sense in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and that there is a constant $C$ such that
\begin{equation}
    \int_{\{|x - y| < 1\}} |u(y)| dy < C, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n
\end{equation}
Show that $u$ is constant.

My approach is as follows:

If $u$ is harmonic then whenever $x \neq 0$, $|u(x)|$ is also harmonic. Thus, by mean value theorem, we have that $|u(x)| = \int_{\{|x - y| < 1\}} |u(y)| dy < C,$. This implies that $u$ is bounded so that by Louville's theorem, it follows that $u$ is constant.

Is this correct or complete? Any feedback is welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that $|u(x)|$ is not harmonic in general ($|u(x)|$ is not even differentiable in general), unless $u$ is constant. But you need only the inequality:

$$ |u(x)| = \left| \frac{1}{|B(1)|} \int_{|y-x|<1} u(y) dy\right| \le \frac{1}{|B(1)|}\int_{|y-x|<1} |u(y)| dy \le \frac{C}{|B(1)|}.$$

The first equality comes from the mean value formula for $u$.

Then $u$ is bounded and, like you say, is constant.